# IF and Max Formula through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013

I have applied the VBA formula but not return the results

Below formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(I6),IF(VALUE(I6)=$L$6,MAX($H$6:$H$79),NA()),NA())
```

VBA:

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("D5").Offset(1, 1 + 3).Resize(m + 1, 1)
Range("D5").Offset(1, 1 + 6).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(" & Range("D5").Offset(1, 1 + 4).Address(0, 0) & ",IF(VALUE(" & Range("D5").Offset(1, 1 + 4).Address(0, 0) & "=" & Range("D5").Offset(1, 3 + 5).Address(1, 1) & ",MAX(" & MyRange.Address & "),NA()),NA())"
```

Thanks for Advance

Comment: You forgot the closing parentheses after each `Address(0,0)`. To not let it happen again, in the future use a variable for the formula and add a `Debug.Print` line to test what it looks like. Only when you're satisfied with the result, test writing to the worksheet.

Comment: You missed closing parenthesis for `ISNUMBER` and `VALUE`. The formula should look like `"=IF(ISNUMBER(" & Range("D5").Offset(1, 1 + 4).address(0, 0) &  "),IF(VALUE(" & Range("D5").Offset(1, 1 + 4).address(0, 0) & ")=" & Range("D5").Offset(1, 3 + 5).address(1, 1) &  ",MAX(" & MyRange.address & "),NA()),NA())"`...